# js differ click and double click

Tags: javascript, click, ondblclick

I am trying to differentiate `click` and `dblclick` events by javascript. I tried `stopPropagation` in `dblclick` however did not work. hence I coded my own function using `setTimeout` tries to avoid calling the other when calling one.

```js
/* dblclick differ click 
takes two functions as param and one element 
to bind the event listener on
*/
function cdblclick(click, dblclick, el){
  el.cooled = true;
  el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(el.cooled){
      setTimeout(function(){
        if(!el.cdblc){el.cdblc = 0}
        el.cdblc++;
        if(el.cdblc === 1){
          setTimeout(function(){
            if(!el.doubled){
              console.log('click')
              // click();
              el.cdblc = 0;
              el.cooled = true;
              el.doubled = false;
            }
          }, 300);
        }else if(el.cdblc === 2){
          console.log('double')
          // dblclick();
          el.doubled = true;
          el.cdblc = 0;
          el.cooled = true;
        }else{
        }
      }, 250);
    }
  });
}
```

however, it does not work properly. I will be so glad if you ca give me a hand.

---

Thanks for the suggestions of divide to two elements, however, I must implement both events on the same element

---

#### solution

thanks to all the helps.

```js
/* dblclick differ click 
takes two functions as param and one element 
to bind the event listener on
*/
function cdblclick(click, dblClick, el) {
  let clickedTimes = 0;
  const incrementClick = () => {
    clickedTimes++;
  };
  const reset = () => {
    clickedTimes = 0;
  };
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    incrementClick();
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (clickedTimes === 1) {
        click(e);
      } else if (clickedTimes >= 2) {
        dblClick(e);
      }
      reset();
    }, 300);
  });
}
```

Comment: You should clear the *click-timeout* once you have more than one click.

Comment: You have to clear your `cdblc` in the empty `else{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to execute the single click at all in case of double, you can use a timeout like you did. You just have to reset the counter and the timeout properly. You do not reset `el.cdblc` on your last empty `else`.

**Be aware, that this delays normal clicks.**

```js
/* dblclick differ click 
takes two functions as param and one element 
to bind the event listener on
*/
function cdblclick(click, dblclick, el){
  //REM: Storing the values in an object instead of own element properties
  let tObject = {
    Clicks: 0,
    onClick: click,
    onDblClick: dblclick
  };

  //el.cooled = true;
  el.addEventListener('click', function(object){
    object.Clicks += 1;

    //REM: Starting the click..
    if(object.Clicks === 1){
      object.Timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
        //REM: Execute click if not stopped
        if(typeof object.onClick == 'function'){
          object.onClick()
        };

        //REM: Resetting the click count
        object.Clicks = 0

        /*if(!el.cdblc){el.cdblc = 0}
        el.cdblc++;
        if(el.cdblc === 1){
          setTimeout(function(){
            if(!el.doubled){
              console.log('click')
              // click();
              el.cdblc = 0;
              el.cooled = true;
              el.doubled = false;
            }
        */
      }.bind(this, object), 300)
    }
    //REM: Unless we have triple clicks, there is only double left
    else{
        //REM: Cancel the single click
        window.clearTimeout(object.Timeout);
    
        //REM: Execute double click
        if(typeof object.onDblClick === 'function'){
            object.onDblClick()
          };

        //REM: Resetting the click count
        object.Clicks = 0
        
        /*
          console.log('double')
          // dblclick();
          el.doubled = true;
          el.cdblc = 0;
          el.cooled = true;
       */
    }
  }.bind(el, tObject))
};

document.querySelector('b').onclick = cdblclick(
  function(){console.log('onclick')},
  function(){console.log('ondblclick')},
  document.body
);
```

```html
<b>Click me</b>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution where each 'click counter' is specific to each element, so `onclick` functions outside the element will not be effected...

```js
const singleOrDouble = ({target}) => {
  if (isNaN(target.cn)) {
    target.cn = 1 
  } else {
    target.cn++
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (target.cn == 1) {
     console.log('once')
     target.cn = 0
    }
    if (target.cn > 1) {
      console.log('twice')
      target.cn = 0
    }
  }, 500)  
}
```

```html
<p onclick="singleOrDouble(event)">Click me</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this will work.

```
function cDblClick(click, dblClick, el) {
  let clickedTimes = 0;
  const incrementClick = () => {
    clickedTimes++;
  };
  const reset = () => {
    clickedTimes = 0;
  };

  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    incrementClick();

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (clickedTimes === 1) {
        click();
      } else if (clickedTimes === 2) {
        dblClick();
      }

      reset();
    }, 300);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try ondblclick  js listner like this :

```js
document.getElementById('click').onclick = function() { console.log("click"); }
document.getElementById('dblclick').ondblclick = function() { console.log("double click"); }
```

```html
<div>
   <button id="click"> click </button>
   <button id="dblclick"> double click </button>
   
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to differ click and dbclick:

```js
document.getElementById('click').onclick = function() { 
//do something if click
}
document.getElementById('click').ondblclick = function() { 
//do something if dbclick
}
```

```html
<div>
   <button id="click"> click or dbclick? </button> 
 </div>
```